# Multiple <audio> tags are played simultaneously on same HTML page in iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, audio

Using HTML5  tag, I created a web page for iPhone and iPad with multiple  files. All these  tags are created dynamically using java script. We can play multiple audio files at the same time and the audio gets overlapped.

I have tried a couple of solutions but none of them worked for me. I need a work around using java script or jquery to allow user to only play one audio file at a time.

Below is the code snippet of what i am actually doing.

```
callDetailItems.push("<div class='notes' id='"+ notes.note_id +"'><div class='existingnote'><span class='existingnotetoedit' id='notedId"+ notes.note_id +"'>" + note_text + "</span><div><audio class=audioNote id='"+ notes.note_id +"' src='"+ audioNotePath +"' type=audio/mpeg preload=auto></audio><span class='timeduration'>" + timeDuration + "</span></div><span><p class=createdBy>-" +  noteCreatedBy + "," + noteCreatedDateTimeAMPM + "</p></span></div><div class='notemenu'><div class='deletcallenote'>Delete Note</div></div><div class='editaddednote edtaddnote'><textarea class='editnt' id='editnt'></textarea><p class='formbtadd'><input type='button' value='Cancel' class='canceleditnote editnotebt' style='background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #848484;border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;color: #FFFFFF;font-size: 1em;padding: 5px; vertical-align:top;' data-role='none' /><input type='button' value='Save' class='saveeditnote editnotebt' style='background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #848484;border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;color: #FFFFFF;font-size: 1em;padding: 5px;' data-role='none' /> </p></div></div>");
```

Please provide with some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following to solve the problem of multiple audio notes playing. Now using the following code only one audio is played at one time. Also, if you pause one audio and play another one and then play the paused audio then it will play from the point it was paused.

Below this is the HTML code

```
<div class='audiowithduration' id='"+ notes.note_id +"'>
  <div id='"+ notes.note_id +"' class='detailrecording'>
   <img src='../images/playrecord.png' class='detailplay' onclick='playAudio(this);'/>
   <img src='../images/pauserecord.png' class='detailpause' onclick='pauseAudio(this);' hidden/>    
    <input class='seekbar' type='range' step='any' min='0' value='0' disabled />
  </div>
  <span class='timeduration'>" + timeDuration + "</span>
  <audio class='audioNote' id='"+ notes.note_id +"' src='"+ audioNotePath +"' type=audio/mpeg preload='metadata'>
  </audio>
</div>
```

Below is the javascript code

```
/*Function to play an audio note*/
function playAudio(parentElement)
{
var audioNoteId = parentElement.parentNode.id;
//Get the audio id and tag value to play
        var song = $('#'+audioNoteId).find('.audioNote')[0];

        //Pause any audio that is already playing
        if (curPlaying)
        {
            $("audio", "#" + curPlaying)[0].pause();
        }

        if (song.paused)
        {
            song.play();
            curPlaying = $('#'+audioNoteId).find('.audioNote')[0].id;
        }
        else
        {
            song.pause();
        }
}

/*Function to pause an audio note*/
function pauseAudio(parentElement)
{
var audioNoteId = parentElement.parentNode.id;
//Get the audio id and tag value to pause
    var song = $('#'+audioNoteId).find('.audioNote')[0];
    song.pause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you're asking is how to stop any other currently playing audio files when you start playing a new one. Likely the easiest way would be to hold a reference to your audio element in JavaScript as soon as you start playing it. Then, when you go to play another file, you can call `stop` on your reference to the currently playing file, start playing the new one, and update the reference to it.

Comment: No I am not calling the play method any where in java script or any other java script file. The files are not getting played automatically. I click on the play button of each audio tag and then they start playing.

Comment: Ah okay, I guess I misunderstood the question. What is it then that you're unable to do?

Comment: I want to play one <audio> file at one time. If a <audio> file is already playing, and I click on play of another <audio> file, then the previously playing file should stop and then the new one should play. Actually, I have images which can help understand the problem more clearly, but I am not able to upload them as I do not have enough credits/badges

Comment: I searched a lot for similar posts and also on google for solutions, but it was not a success. I tried the same code with different devices and OS and found something interesting. The <audio> tag works great on iPhone 4 with OS version 6.1. Not more than one <audio> files are played at the same time. But when tried running the same code on iPad with the same version it did not work. Also, it did not work for devices with iOS 7 and above.

Comment: Could you post some of the code you're trying to use that's not working? The default behavior for handling multiple audio files might have changed between OS versions, but given that you have the ability to programmatically play and pause/stop each individual audio file, you should be able to accomplish what you're trying to do.